# How to build a mobile app with an App Engine backend tutorial: Not an App Engine Project

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I am new to App Engine: I'm trying to follow the tutorial [How to build a mobile app with an App Engine backend](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial#ecdp). When I get to the step "Generate a Cloud Endpoints Class and Library," I try right-clicking the CheckIn.java class and running "generate cloud endpoint class." I then get the error "Not an app engine project." I don't think I missed anything in the tutorial. I also had no issues when I generated the app engine back-end. Any idea of how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Right click on your android project - > Google -> Generate AppEngine Backend
2. Write the endpoints there
3. Generate client library

You could write only the @Entity class then -> right click -> Google -> Generate Could Endpoint Class, that would generate the C.R.U.D operations. then you could generate the endpont library for android.

HINT: New -> Other -> Android -> Appengine Connected Android Project

You need both appengine and android projects to link them.